# Jenkins file executing a sh, can not escape double quote character

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkinsfile that describe a pipeline.

In one of my steps I am trying to assign a value from a curl like so :

```
sh '''
value=$(curl "http://someUrl/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\":\",//crumb)")
//some commands
'''
```

But somehow it is calling

```
curl 'http://someUrl.com/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,:,//crumb)'
```

instead of

```
curl 'http://someUrl.com/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'
```

So it results to an error, I thought in shell to escape a character we must use '\' , what is wrong in my command?

(I tried in gitbash the curl with the good url it's working)

Comment: did you tried some thing like "":"" this?

Answer (score 0):

Using triple '\' worked  :

```
value=$(curl "http://someUrl/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\\\":\\\",//crumb)")
```